# Combining Masking and Indexing in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider the following data frame :

```
population_dict = {'California': 38332521,
                   'Texas': 26448193,
                   'New York': 19651127,
                   'Florida': 19552860,
                   'Illinois': 12882135}
pop = pd.Series(population_dict)

area_dict = {'California': 423967, 'Texas': 695662, 'New York': 141297,
             'Florida': 170312, 'Illinois': 149995}
area = pd.Series(area_dict)

data = pd.DataFrame({'area' : area, 'pop' : pop})
```

I can perform masking and indexing on columns in the same line as follows :

```
In [492]:data.loc[data.density > 100, ['pop', 'density']]
Out[492]: 
               pop     density
New York  19651127  139.076746
Florida   19552860  114.806121
```

But if I need to do this masking and indexing on rows? Something like:
data.loc[data.density > 100, ['New York']]. But this statement obviously gives an error.

Comment: When I do: data.loc[data.density > 100, ['pop', 'density']] it gives me `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'density'`, and indeed data does not have a density column

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion! Forgot to add the piece of code below:

data['density'] = data['pop'] / data['area']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to extract information, chaining `loc` works just fine:

```
data[data.density > 100].loc[['New York']]
```

Output:

```
            area       pop     density
New York  141297  19651127  139.076746
```

Comment: Thanks @Quang Hoang! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
data2 = data.loc[data.density > 100, ['pop', 'density']]
print(data2.loc[data2.index == 'New York'])
```